# auth::id(); returns 'null' or auth::check(); returns 'false'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-authentication

I have tried different methods discussed in here but not successful to my problem.
Assumptions:

1. Failure to group routes under the same middleware group.
2. Get all the sessions required from web middleware and replace them into
   global middleware
   But I don't know how? help, please.

**Controller**

```
class StarterController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
     $id = Auth::check();
     dd($id);
   }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/auth.register', 'AuthController@getRegister')->name('auth')->middleware('guest');
Route::get('/auth.login', 'AuthController@getLogin')->name('auth')->middleware('guest');
```

Comment: please copy paste code here , dont attach pictures of code

Comment: What seems to be the problem? When no user is authenticated that are the correct responses.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call user helper function first :

```
Auth::user()->id;
```